# Unit Test for controller in AngularJs Failed

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Here is my controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('pulseOneApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        'content': {
          templateUrl: 'components/version/about.html',
          controller: 'AboutController'
        }
      },
      authNotRequired: true
    });
  })

  .controller('AboutController', ['$scope', '$state', 'session', '$pulseOneProps', '$filter', 'propertiesServices', function ($scope, $state, session, $pulseOneProps, $filter, propertiesServices) {

    /**
     * @function  getServerVersion
     * @description gets the serverVersion from $pulseOneProps if exist, else makes a REST Api call using propertiesServices.
     * @returns string
     */
    var getServerVersion = function () {
      var systemProperties,serverVersion;
      if ((angular.isDefined($pulseOneProps))  && $pulseOneProps !== null) {
        systemProperties = $pulseOneProps.getProperties();
        if(systemProperties) {
          return $filter('filter')(systemProperties, {name: 'server_version'})[0].value;
        }
        else{
          //when the session exist and not able to retrieve $pulseOneProps then do REST Api call and update the systemProperties
          session.validateSession().then(function() {
            propertiesServices.getPulseOneProperties().then(function (systemProperties) {
              serverVersion=$filter('filter')(systemProperties, {name: 'server_version'})[0].value;
              // This will update the UI when serverVersion is available
              $scope.serverVersion = (serverVersion) ? serverVersion: false;
            });
          });
        }
      }
      return null; // if none of the above cases are valid then don't display the server version.
    };

    var serverVersion=getServerVersion();
    $scope.serverVersion = (serverVersion) ? serverVersion: false;

    $scope.goTo = function() {
      session.validateSession().then(function() {
        $state.go('app.dashboard');
      })
      .catch(function() {
        $state.go('login');
      });
    };
  }]);
```

and Here is my Unit Test for this controller to make sure the function goTo is the function:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: AboutCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
  beforeEach(module('ps.authentication.services'));
  beforeEach(module('ps.version'));
  beforeEach(module('pulseOneApp'));
  beforeEach(module('ps.components.properties'));


  var scope, AboutController;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    AboutController = _$controller_('AboutController', {
      $scope: scope
     });
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should find to goTo function', function () {
    expect(typeof scope.goTo).toBe('function');
  });
});
```

The unit test is failed and I don't know what was wrong with this unit test.
Any suggestion what was the issue here.
**Note : The error message is : scope is undefined.**

Thanks in advance
-k

Comment: And it fails with error message which is?...

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.goTo') in /git/pws/pulse-workspace-ui/unity/app/components/version/about.controller.spec.js (line 23)
 /git/pws/pulse-workspace-ui/unity/app/components/version/about.controller.spec.js:23:24

Comment: The reason for `scope` to not be an object is an error that happens in `beforeEach`. You should get errors before 'should find to goTo function' spec. If you're using PhantomJS to run tests, replace it with Chrome, the former is known for swallowing errors. The error may happen in any relevant module, e.g. `angular.module('pulseOneApp')` presumes that the module was defined, but there's no `angular.module('pulseOneApp', [...])`  in the code that you've posted. For this reason it is beneficial to isolate each tested module as much as possible, so the problem could be easily spotted.